# making ajax requests to fetch dictionary content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, electron

I am trying to create a password generator with the ability to create passwords with real English words. I have 5 csv files, each file containing words of different character ie(3 letter word, 4 letter word). My question is regarding efficiency and how i should go about approaching this problem. Is it better to put these contents on a server, and query for them or should i just keep them inside files and make ajax calls to load all 5 files when the user wants to create a password with real English words. The total size of all 5 files are about 600-700kb and if i load these files using an ajax call i would be able to find the word i want in a constant time. Is it bad to have to load an additional 700kb of data each time the user loads the application?

Comment: loads the application? Once your user picks a password he's likely not to come back. If he does, well - waiting that fraction of a second for you to generate a  new password seems not a big deal. Take a dictionary, **one** doctionary, you don't need 5, or more files... but DON'T use *only* English words, use also some special characters and numbers - make also sure the password is longer than 12 characters, like i.e: `elegant%DOGseems45`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan right, i was saying the user had the "option" to create a password using english words. the reason i choose to split them up into 5 different files was because i could easily parse them into their respective arrays to only look for words with specific amount of characters hence the constant time complexity.

Comment: Don't :) take an EN dictionary Array, store it into a file, create a while loop, grab words till `pw.length < 15` on every iteration pick from your Array a word. You could prevent to pick too long words by initially filtering and rewriting your dic. to not contain words longer that 9 characters. Make also a function to drop here and there a random character or special character, and a function to uppercase and insert numbers of random length - all that in an unpredictable pseudo-random manner. If you know your dic. has 40000 words, that's 40000 random points.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thats exactly why i have 5 files so i know how long the characters are. First file has 3 character words, second file has 4 character words, third file has 5 character words. i just needed to generate a random number and pick at the index. Anyways my question was not about password strength but about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example using a dictionary of words of length 3 to 7, without special characters and numbers:

```js
function generatePassword() {
  console.time("generatePassword");

  $.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rokobuljan/3-7-en-dic/master/dic-3-7.txt", function(data) {
  
    var dic = data.split("\n"),
      len = dic.length,
      pwd = "";

    while (pwd.length < 15) pwd += dic[~~(Math.random() * len)];

    $("#resultPassword").text(pwd);
    
    console.timeEnd("generatePassword");
  });
}

// The dictionary holds 125,409 lines of 3-7 char words.

// The first time we generate will take longer (0.5s ~ 1s)
// since we're still fetching our file
generatePassword();

// Now that the browser has cached the file,
// subsequent clicks will take ~28ms to generate
$("#generatePassword").on("click", generatePassword);
```

```html
<button id="generatePassword">&#x21bb;</button>
<span id="resultPassword"></span>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```